# adding time() after a javascript file call a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, php, file, load

I've watched a PHP tutorial on youtube about loading javascript file. And at the end of the file path, he added a time() function so to avoid the js file not getting update after refresh if he happened to edit it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js?<?=time(); ?>"></script>
```

However, when I try to do this with jquery-ui.js, it took about 7 seconds to load the page. When I removed the time(), the page loaded right away.

Why did this happen?

Comment: 7 seconds is a bit excessive. Your JS file would have to be like 30MB on my connection for that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your browser doesn't cache this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js?<?=time(); ?>"></script>
```

which turns to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js?12321321"></script>
```

Which basically is considered a different file, every seconds

The assumption you have "page loaded right away" is because the javascript is already loaded, which means, you will experience the "7 seconds to load" the first time you load it.

Comment: you are correct, I used some random number at the end and every first time it took 7 seconds, after that the page loaded very fast. I guess I'm going to remove the time variable completely for those files with bigger size.

Answer (score 1):

If value returned by time method changes every time then browser will not cache js file and for every request it will load js from server and that is why it is taking time.

Instead of time we can have some constant value(for version) and whenever we change the js we can change that constant(it will make sure that updated file is loaded into browser).

```
     <script>
      var version=1.0; //version will be global variable, should be change when js file is changed
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js?v=version"></script>
```

Same version constant you can apply to all js file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the time to the end of the JavaScript (or any file) forces the browser to think it is a new file (because the file names do not match).

Usually this is not required in production environments.

It can be very useful during development though because cached files can generate sometimes unexpected results